# How to use Transfer Learning for Text classification in Apples Create ML?

Tags: swift, xcode, developer-tools, transfer-learning, createml

I was watching https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/428/, where Transfer Learning is used for text classification in Create ML.

I wanted to do the same and created Datasets with the following structure:

- Folders where the Name of the Folder is the Label / Answer to a Question.
- Inside each folder there are 10 text files with Questions.

Pretty much the same Idea like in the Video.

When I now choose Transfer Learning (like in the Video) and start to train, the Window tells me "Model has no Data" (see Screenshot).

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5LEE.png)

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your Error Screenshot, you are missing the test data.